# VB 2008 Search dataset.table by Textbox.Text as variable

Tags: database, vb.net, dataset

Respected Sir,

VB 2008. Me trying to search a dataset table by Textbox.Text as variable. But its giving error, am i doing any errors in this code ?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    
  Handles Button1.Click 

  Dim myID = TextBox1.Text
  Dim myArray() As DataRow
        Dim i As Integer
        myArray = myDataSet.myTable.Select("PRODUCTID" = myID)
        For i = 0 To (myArray.Length - 1)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(myArray(i)("PRODUCTID").ToString)
        Next

  End Sub
```

yours faithfully
Murulimadhav

Comment: Possible problems: You need to turn option strict ON. Your dataset may not have "PRODUCTID" as a column, or myID may be a null string.

Comment: Also, declaring it as myArray() with parenthesis is an array of datarows, not one datarow.

Comment: Create a DataView from your DataSet table. Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(someDataset.Tables(0)). Then set the RowFilter in the DataView.

Comment: @sparkysword `DataTable.Select` always returns an array of datarows, not just one. The code is correct in that aspect.

Comment: Consider me corrected! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think of the select command as the WHERE part of an SQL Select. Your code should be something like:

```
myArray = myDataSet.myTable.Select("PRODUCTID = " & myID)
```

This assumes you have a field named PRODUCTID  in that table and it is numeric. If it were text/string, you would need to enclose in quotes:

```
myArray = myDataSet.myTable.Select("PRODUCTID = '" & myID & "'")
```

Comment: Respected Sir, Thanks a lot, its working now perfect, yours faithfully

Comment: Repected Sir,
 I am using this code  myArray = myDs.myTable.Select("title = '" & myTitle & "'") to filter out the duplicate titles  in my savebutton function .
but now i am getting a trouble. It is if  i include a "Apostrophe"  together with my title input, for example  if title = Coconut's, then when i am saving i get a error message "The expression contains an invalid string constant" and debug is pointing to the above code. Is there any solutions for this ? or i have to find other method to filter out duplicates before saving ?
yours faithfully
Murulimadhav

Comment: Respected Sir, i guess i got it. myTitle = TitleTextBox.Text.Replace("'", "''"), is this is the right method ? Yours faithfully